# 60's-70's SF short story, worldwide transport beam system goes wrong, a man gets an upside down head

Tags: story-identification, short-stories

I read this approx 1990 but I think it was in an anthology with a lot of stories from the 1960's and 1970's.

A man steps into his daily transporter booth and sits down, a few seconds later he goes to leave but the door won't open. While he waits for assistance he realises his head is on upside down and he starts crying, this is awkward because his nose overflows and runs down into his eyes.

A medical team arrive and take him to a holding area, there are others there who have had transportation mishaps, somebody with back to front legs and (I think) a woman with her eyes on the side of her head.

It is explained to him that he's one of the very rare casualties in the booth system, the only chance is to keep transporting him until he is OK. He notices a grotesque figure with multiple arms and legs entwined, this was a courting couple who purposely crammed into a booth together so they could be as one.

I think his first repair hop almost succeeds, his head etc is OK but his nose is still upside down, therefore he'll have to beam again.

I really can't remember what happens next.

Comment: “I teleported home last night with Ron and Sid and Meg. - - 

Ron stole Meggy's heart away and I got Sidney's leg.”

Comment: I remember the story -- it was from Analog. The line that comes to me was "I'm sorry Mr. X, but your heart isn't in the right place."

Comment: @Mark Olson yes! Now you've said it I also remember that line

Comment: I have a vague memory that the story was by W. McFarlane or John Philliphent, or Jack Wodhams -- one of Campbell's private stable of relatively minor writers.  But looking at ISFDB, I don't see a title which leaps out at me and I don't have the heart to read through ten years of late Campbell Analog for find it!

Comment: @MarkOlson: "Mr. Traff," he said, "I know you are a generous man who gives readily to charity, but I have to tell you this: Your heart is not in the right place."

Answer (score 7, accepted):

As one of the commentators suggested, this sounds like "[There is a crooked man](https://www.isfdb.org/cgi-bin/title.cgi?45538)", a novella by Jack Wodhams, first published in 1967. It deals with a number of grotesque accidents occuring with a teleportation system, including Mr Frederic Traff:

> Mr. Frederic Traff looked down at himself and choked back a cry of
> dismay. He had been incorrectly reassembled. His legs were on
> backwards and his toes pointed to the rear.
>
> Mr. Traff teetered unfamiliarly.
>
> His arms did not feel right. He examined them. His elbows pointed
> forward, his palms faced outward from his sides.
>
> "Oh, God," he groaned unhappily. "Oh, God."
>
> A tear overflowed his eye and trickled down the back of his neck.

and a courting couple:

> Mr. Traff stared horrified as they wheeled the new admission past his
> door. It was a grotesque human octopus, two bodies fantastically
> fused. He shuddered at the incongruous grins on two teenage faces.
>
> A hand on his arm, "We'll try and get your toenails up on top where
> they belong, Mr. Traff."
>
> Mr. Traff gestured down the corridor. "What... was that?"
>
> "Uh? Oh, that. Just a couple of kids. That's the third pair in two
> weeks. New craze they have. They call it togetherness."